# Is there a Java library for muslim prayer times calculation?

Tags: java, web-services

Can anyone tell me where to find a Java library that does Muslim prayer time calculation based on the city? Maybe a web service? I would prefer a Java library.

Comment: Sounds like a project you could undertake.

Comment: I agree with AlbertoPL - it could be an interesting project!

Comment: @hkhalifa how u resolve your issue ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891905/12478830

Answer (score 8):

http://www.javafr.com/codes/PRAYER-ALERT-SALA_40601.aspx

hello, it's not a library but a student project. But quite well executed.

Or : http://www.directionsmag.com/article.php?article_id=2956
A method to calcul prayer time with google map+local time ( in short : check where you are, check how far your are from the Makkah , apply the right formula )

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of the PrayTimes library.

http://praytimes.org/code/

It's originally written in JavaScript, but there are ports to other languages as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Ubuntu Muslim Edition](http://www.sabily.org/website/) uses this type of features in a calendar, maybe you could search around there

Comment: I found this library http://www.arabeyes.org/project.php?proj=ITL but its in c++ , I think i will have to write one in Java

Comment: do give it a try. I would love to see it in action.

Answer (score 3):

Best is https://github.com/abodehq/Pray-Times for this question. It includes java, objective C,PHP, C#, javascript, python, c++ code implementation. It supports different methods and calculation is based gps position.Calculation Methods are Ithna Ashari,University of Islamic Sciences, Karachi, Islamic Society of North America (ISNA),Muslim World League (MWL),Umm al-Qura, Makkah,Egyptian General Authority of Survey,Institute of Geophysics, University of Tehran,Custom Setting. Juristic Methods are Shafii, Hanafi. Adjusting Methods for Higher Latitudes. Formats are 24-hour format/12-hour format/12-hour format with no suffix/floating point number.

Comment: Use this library:
http://praytimes.org/wiki/Prayer_Times_Calculation.

Very well written. Code available in all popular programming languages

Answer (score 0):

I think that is come out port of ITL for Java on [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jitl/)